# How can I get percentage of pull docker image?

Tags: python, docker, dockerhub, dockerpy

It I using `docker pull` by command or docker-py API `c.pull(repository, tag=None, stream=False)`.

How can I get pull(download) progress of this image?

Comment: You need progress for whole image or for layers? It might be hard to get it for whole image as docker doesn't know how many layers image will contain. Layer can depend on other layers and this will show up only after downloading it.

Comment: So, I cannot get numbers of layers right? I can just wait for it until pull finish.

Comment: You can experiment with Registry API to get info about layers before downloading. Doc is here: https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/

Answer (score 0):

docker-py priovides client pull API that provides completed count, and total count. You can divide them to get the percentage you need.

For example, this snippet:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
resp = client.api.pull(image_name, stream=True, decode=True)
for line in resp:
    print(json.dumps(line, indent=4))
```

would print:

```
{
    "status": "Downloading",
    "progressDetail": {
        "current": 12253570,
        "total": 12627702
    },
    "progress": "[================================================>  ]  12.25MB/12.63MB",
    "id": "14e6ed0b1573"
}
{
    "status": "Downloading",
    "progressDetail": {
        "current": 12384642,
        "total": 12627702
    },
    "progress": "[=================================================> ]  12.38MB/12.63MB",
    "id": "14e6ed0b1573"
}
```

For each message, you can get the current/total to get the functionality you want.

I wrote a program with rich library to show a progress bar. It can print the progress for each layer individually (including if it is for download vs extracting that layer).

```
import docker
from rich.progress import Progress

tasks = {}

# Show task progress (red for download, green for extract)
def show_progress(line, progress):
    if line['status'] == 'Downloading':
        id = f'[red][Download {line["id"]}]'
    elif line['status'] == 'Extracting':
        id = f'[green][Extract  {line["id"]}]'
    else:
        # skip other statuses
        return

    if id not in tasks.keys():
        tasks[id] = progress.add_task(f"{id}", total=line['progressDetail']['total'])
    else:
        progress.update(tasks[id], completed=line['progressDetail']['current'])

def image_pull(image_name):
    print(f'Pulling image: {image_name}')
    with Progress() as progress:
        client = docker.from_env()
        resp = client.api.pull(image_name, stream=True, decode=True)
        for line in resp:
            show_progress(line, progress)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Pull a large image
    IMAGE_NAME = 'bitnami/pytorch'
    image_pull(IMAGE_NAME)
```

The output for this looks like in the attached image. It shows download statuses in red, and extract status in green.

[Python program to show docker image pull progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXP5H.png)